# Remote access to leaf node when using memsql-spark-connector

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

I'm trying to test [memsql-spark-connector](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector) and for this I created a single node MemSQL cluster on AWS (https://docs.memsql.com/docs/quick-start-with-amazon-webservices).

On my laptop I want to run a Spark application **in local mode**. This application should simply create `Dataframe` for a table and collect all rows. Here is the code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Test App")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("memsql.host", "x.x.x.x")
  .set("memsql.port", "3306")
  .set("memsql.user", "root")
  .set("memsql.password", "1234")
  .set("memsql.defaultDatabase", "dataframes_test")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val memsql = new MemSQLContext(sc)

val df = memsql.table("person")

df.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

where `x.x.x.x` is the address of my AWS instance.

The problem is although I can connect to MemSQL server from my laptop, `memsql-spark-connector` tries to access leaf node directly (i.e. connect to port 3307 instead of 3306). And when this happens I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'108.208.196.149' (using password: YES)
```

But `root` user actually does have all permissions:

```
memsql> show grants for 'root'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A49656EC00D74D3524072F3452C1FBA7A1F3B561' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it possible to grant permissions to leaf nodes so that this connection to `x.x.x.x:3307` is successful as well?

I realize that it's probably not the way it's designed to be used, but I want to do it this way only for testing. It's convinient to debug when everything is in a single JVM, and I don't want to bother about Spark installation for now. I could install MemSQL locally to solve my problem, but I can't do this on Mac (is this right, BTW?).

Any help appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**: Just tried to connect locally on the server and still doesn't work:

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ memsql -P 3307 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Password I'm providing is correct, on AWS it's an instance ID, so very hard to make a mistake.

This means that it wouldn't work even if I had Spark executor on the same instance with the leaf node. Feels like something is wrong with my setup, but I actually didn't change any settings, all are defaults.

Are master node and leaf node supposed to use the same credentials? Is there a way to setup them for the leaf separately?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the login was denied, i.e. incorrect username/password (not that the user doesn't have enough permissions). Make sure the password you are using in the spark connector matches the password on all the nodes.

Comment: It does match. I can't even connect locally with `memsql -P 3307 -u root -p`, providing the same password I'm using everywhere (on AWS it's the instance ID, so it's very hard to make a mistake). Are master node and leaf node supposed to use same credentials?

Comment: Yeah, that means the user/password you are trying to use is wrong on that node. Note that each node has its own independent credentials, so your master and leaf nodes in this case apparently have different passwords.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The password for leaf node is empty. Apparently when installing from AWS Marketplace, the default root password is changed for master node, but not for leaf node. Strange, but it is what it is. Thanks for help!